# changing the background on keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the background color of ul when keydown event occurs.when i press the down arrow the corresponding ul should change the background color.

Here is my code

```
 <div class=".container">
 <ul>
 <li>one</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
 <li>two</li>
 </ul> 
 <ul>
 <li>three</li>
 </ul>     
 <div>

 var chosen = "";
 $(document).keydown(function(e){ // 38-up, 40-down
 if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
 if(chosen === "") {
 chosen = 0;
 } else if((chosen+1) < $('.container ul').length) {
 chosen++; 
 }
 $('.container ul').removeClass('selected');
 $('.container ul:eq('+chosen+')').addClass('selected');
 return false;
 }
 if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
 if(chosen === "") {
 chosen = 0;
 } else if(chosen > 0) {
 chosen--;            
 }
 $('.container ul').removeClass('selected');
 $('.container ul:eq('+chosen+')').addClass('selected');
 return false;
 }

 });

 .selected
 {
 background:red;
 }
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6y6/

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
<div class=".container">
```

to this:

```
<div class="container">
```

Comment: when i use this code in my project the background color immediately disappears from the ul event though return false is there after addClass

Comment: may be some other css/js on page conflicting

Comment: i tried by setting css instead of addClass and also tried moving js to different file, same issue exists